# Is it possible to push for WebDriver path with some extra argument like file path to open in browser?

Tags: java, windows, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to import files when testing the chromium-based apps. I tried:

1. Pushing file path to input type=file in Selenium code but it doesn't
   work, just got the error "File is used by another program" in my app.
2. Upload file just by clicking but this mechanism opens the WPF window and can't handle it with Selenium. Need to avoid the use of tools like Sikuli or AutoIT bec tests should work in a headless environment without VNC.

I wWould like to use Windows mechanism for opening files - `path-to-app.exe path-to-file.jpg` and create Chrome Driver in this way:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", driverPath);
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.setBinary(appPath);
chromeOptions.addArguments(" \"C:\\file.jpg\"");
chromeOptions.addArguments("--remote-debugging-port=9222");
ChromeDriver chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

To have a file opened at the app start. With such arguments app starting in the proper way - with the file opening. But I can't use the driver to control the app. Error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: 
chrome not reachable
```

Answer (score 0):

Just found some solution to upload files to chromium based apps in windows headless environemt. Made this ChromeDriver creating class and push tests to Jenkins, successfully completed.

```
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    pr = rt.exec(
            this.appPath
                    + " src/main/resources/models/inputs/marvin.STL"
                    + " --headless"
                    + " --remote-debugging-port=9222"
                    + " --user-data-dir=\"src/main/resources/chromiumprofile\"");
    System.out.println("Process opened with filepath as argument:");
    System.out.println(pr.info());
    System.out.println("PID: " + pr.pid());
    System.out.println("Is process alive: " + pr.isAlive());
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "src/main/resources/drivers/chromedriver.exe");
    ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
    chromeOptions.setBinary(this.appPath);
    chromeOptions.setHeadless(true);
    chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("debuggerAddress", "127.0.0.1:9222");
    ChromeDriver chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
    System.out.println("Chromium process founded by Chrome Driver");
    System.out.println("Is process alive: " + pr.isAlive());
    return chromeDriver;
```

Use this class to close driver:

```
pr.destroy();
threadSleep(3000);
System.out.println("Process killed");
System.out.println("Is process alive: " + pr.isAlive());
```

xoxo